# Table or Div height and width adjusted to background image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I use a huge image as a background for my div. This image needs to be only shown once, maximum size that the container allows while keeping aspect ratio. Image can have any aspect ratio. The size of container is resizable and can also have any aspect ratio. I managed to achieve that with

```
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image: url("path/to/img");
```

"Over" that image I need an 8x8 table layout that gets bigger and smaller together with background image.

In my jsfiddle example you have the correctly working image (try resizing output window), but I have no idea how to make my table always be directly scaled over that image (Idea is that field A1 will always mark the exact same spot on a specific image, no matter the size, image aspect ratio, container aspect ratio, ...)

https://jsfiddle.net/15uovq7L/4/

If there's no CSS/HTML option for this problem, a jQuery/JavaScript solution is applicable.

Comment: If you are open to use jQuery for this I answered another question today but you can easily apply that here from what I can tell. Here is the plunkr for that: https://plnkr.co/edit/gM2amcTOWa9Abc91imS2?p=preview

Comment: Yeah I figured something like that would be possible using jQuery. I went over that example and I think I can use it for my problem. I'll give it a few hours if someone can come up with pure CSS solution, then I'll get on it. Thanks!

Comment: Pure CSS solution seems nearly impossible since you will need to resize your table height accordingly to your image height, but the fact is you can't know the height of your image before it has been rendered because of the `background-size : contain` property that make it unpredictible. I am afraid In this case you will need the help of Javascript or JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/15uovq7L/5/

set `padding-top: 46%;` in `.tlorisOgledNacrta`.

46% is a image height * 100 / image width

Comment: This is close, but has some drawbacks. My images are not all in the same aspect ratio. And if I used a vertical image, I'd have to flip around padding-top into padding-left? This version also doesn't make the image smaller if I reduce the height of the container.

Comment: use the JavaScript know the height and width of image